# Generating unique serial numbers for medicines in pharmaceuticals industry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

There is a form in the front end to select the Alpha-Chars and Numbers to be included in the **UNIQUE** serial number generation. It can include both **UpperCase & LowerCase** (aA bB) and numbers from **0-9**.

> BUT NO SPECIAL characters.

User can also enter the maximum length for serial number. **Minimum length is 10 and maximum is 20**. So user can select between 10 & 20. User should also select **minimum 5 alphabets and 2 numbers**.
Serial number can't start with numbers, it should always be an alpha-char.

If I need 100 Quantity (batches) then using the selected alpha-chars and numbers we need to generate 100 different serial numbers (in this example I might have selected 'A,B,C,D,E,1,2' in front end). Alpha-Char and Number repetitions are also allowed. Example for serial numbers of length 10 then  AAAaaAAAAA, AAAAAA11AA etc

> So the variables here are Quantity and Alpha-Chars+Numbers selected.

Can you please help me with the serial number generation as per the validations and also be **unique through out the application.**

Trying using sequence in SQL Server 2012 but not able to get a clear idea on how to implement all the validations and also generate unique serial numbers through out the application.

Comment: Using `Guid` would make your and users life easier ;)

Comment: Can you pls help me with the query using the above validations.

Comment: This is too broad a question, you need to have a go see how far you can get and then ask when you get stuck. You can't expect the volunteers here to do it all for you.

Comment: And why do you want to implement this in the database? Why not in the app code?

Comment: ok @DaleBurrell thank you..let me try using Sequence and come up with some solution.

Comment: Unique where? in the database? If you have a maximum ten character serial that has at minimum 5 alphas and 2 numbers, that leaves you **3** places for your unique serial number, You can only have 1,000 of these before you run out. If I misunderstood, you should probably explain a little better. In taking the time to explain you may find you solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `SQL Server` you can do it from the the front end using `Regex` and `Javascript`

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}
```

This will generate the following sequence

- QwDj7X4gfM
- H3G0uCs43Q
- TIoXncEK5N

**[More Demo](http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/#r=hello+%20%28world%7Cto%20you%29)**

Comment: Can we maintain uniqueness when many users are generating serial numbers for the same selection of Alphabets and Numbers from the template.

Comment: These are randomly generated. Before you save it to database just make sure whether its unique or not.. most probably it will be **unique**

Comment: If you're using a database to maintain uniqunes.... then just generate it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, you can extended it if you want. It covers:

- starting with random letter
- variable length
- uniqueness
- letters and numbers (but only capital letters)

So, extended if you need something more complex:

```
SELECT CHAR((RAND()*25 + 65)) -- generate random letter (always start with latter)
       +
       REPLICATE -- varible string (replicating GUID here and the GUID is tend to be unique)
       (
            REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', '')
           ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 3 + 1 -- this will give us one of the following numbers: 1, 2, 3
       );
```

We are using GUID and [REPLICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to generate variable length and uniqueness. You can add one more letter or symbol to make the new string always being at least 10 chars.